# AngularJS ng-pattern regEx not working while using the templateCache

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

I have the below text field where I'm using the ng-pattern for validation and displaying the message using ng-message. The validation works fine with the both the regex (/^\d+$/ or /^[0-9]+$/), but for some reason the regex (/^\d+$/) is returning false even for numeric inputs while using along with the template caching. I couldn't figure out the issue between these two approach. Please find the below templateCaching output. Any help is appreciated.

> input type="text" ng-model="appId" name="appId" class="new-app" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" placeholder="Enter an Application ID" required

**Message :**

> div ng-message="pattern" class="error-messages"

**Not Working with templateCaching:**

> input type="text" ng-model="appId" name="appId" class="new-app" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" placeholder="Enter an Application ID" required

**Working with both templateCaching and as a separate view file:**

input type="text" ng-model="appId" name="appId" class="new-app" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" placeholder="Enter an Application ID" required

> $templateCache.put('/views/layouts/test.html', '<input type="text" ng-model="appId" name="appId" class="new-app" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" placeholder="Enter an Application ID" required>
>   <input type="text" ng-model="appId" name="appId" class="new-app" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" placeholder="Enter an Application ID" required>');

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with templateCache and it was due to having special characters in the pattern like forward slashes and my validatioin was failing. Escaping them fixed the issue:  so if you have `ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"` in html file than it becomes `ng-pattern="/^\\d+$/"` in your templateCache statement.

Comment: Yes it did fixed the issue after updating the regex. Thanks